# Why my IOCTL call work with copy_from_user but not with get_user?

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I am writing a simple driver.

Here I'm learning `ioctl` calls, they work perfect in `copy_to_user` and `copy_from_user` part but not in `get_user` and `put_user` part. It works if I send some data by those functions; problem is when I have to just pass an integer or character value:

```
long ioctl_funcs(struct file *filp,unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{

int ret=0;
int len=10;
char val='d';
char valplusone='d';

switch(cmd) {

case IOCTL_HELLO: 
 printk(KERN_INFO "Hello ioctl world");

case READ_IOCTL:    
        copy_to_user((char *)arg, buf, 200);
     //works fine
        break;

case WRITE_IOCTL:
        copy_from_user(buf, (char *)arg, len);
      //works fine
        buf[6]=' ';
        buf[7]='t';
        buf[8]='o';
        buf[9]='o';
        buf[10]='\n';       
        break;

case READ_ONE:  
        printk(KERN_ALERT "valplusone (put user)is %c \n",valplusone);
        put_user(valplusone,(char __user *) arg);

    //problem       
break;

case WRITE_ONE:  
        if(access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE,(void*)arg,sizeof(char))!=1)
{
printk(KERN_ALERT "access not ok\n");
return -EFAULT;
}
else{

        printk(KERN_ALERT "****arg %l",arg);
        get_user(val,(char __user *)arg);
valplusone='t';
printk(KERN_ALERT "val (get user)is %c\n",val);
break;
}

 } 

return ret;

}
```

in above part it works fine for the
copy to user copy from user but not in case of get_user put_user
now the user side code is:

```
char sent,received;
if(retval=ioctl(fd, WRITE_ONE, sent) < 0)
        perror("third ioctl");
printf("you sent %c\nretval is %d\n",sent,retval);

if(ioctl(fd, READ_ONE, received) < 0)
        perror("fourth ioctl");
printf("you got %c",received);
-----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must pass addresses, not values. Example:

```
if (ioctl(fd, READ_ONE, &received) < 0)
…
```